# MacMini 2009 fan sensor goes to zero after 1500RPM

Tags: hard-drive, catalina, ssd, mac-mini, cooling

This might be pretty obvious that the sensor is bad and I need a replacement, but this sensor is very hard to get here in Brazil, so I'm hoping there's a way to fix the RPM sensor of the MacMini Late 2009.

This is what happens:
[image]

Sometimes the fan lost it's reading and the speed tops maximum with an annoying noise. I noted this happens when in fact the fan needs to speedup. So I stressed the CPU to get a higher RPM on the fans and this is what happens.

When the machine is idle, it behaves as expected:

[image]

In fact I've changed the default hard disk for and SSD drive, upgraded to 8GB of RAM an installed a patched version of Catalina, since it's non supported, pretty "standard" thing to do on this old machines.

So my question is, anyone have a similar situation? Any workaround or fix? And I must answer: can it be related with the installation of an unsupported release of macOS?

EDIT: That's really a hardware issue, this happens on a Linux install that I've made on the machine too.